# Python doesn't deal with char string as expected

Tags: python, for-loop, binaryfiles

I am dealing with a long char string (elements with values 0..255), read directly from a file. I need to divide the string in chunks of 8 bytes. I'd expect this to work:

```
rawindex = file.read()
for chunk in rawindex[::8]:
    print sys.stderr, len(chunk)
```

...but the len() always returns 1. What am I doing wrong?

More info: 
* this is not homework
* I could play with range(,,8), but I would really like to know why the above example doesn't work

Comment: your `8` is not the slice size but the **step** size.

Answer (score 0):

The 'step' parameter in an array's index just iterates each 8th element, not 8 element at once. Your code should look like:

```
step = 8
rawindex = file.read()
for index in range(0, len(rawindex), step):
    print sys.stderr, len(rawindex[index:index+step])
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could just read chunks of the correct size yourself.

```
read_chunk = lambda: my_file.read(8)
for chunk in iter(read_chunk, ''):
    print len(chunk)
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the answer to the question. For reasons too complicated to explain I don't want to read file by chunk, but deal with chunks from a char string.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify the question to remove any mention of files?

Answer (score 0):

```
rawindex = file.read() # this line will return the file read output as a string. For example rawindex = abc efgh ijk
rawindex[::8] # will returns all the eight charactors from the above string. so the result will be 'ah'
```

so effectively the for loop will be `for chunk in 'ah':`
In the first loop chunk will be a. len('a') will be 1. So always the len(chunk) will return 1.

I think you should use range in stead of rowindex[::8].